# Issue with After Insert Trigger Returning NULL in SQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm facing a problem with an 'after insert' trigger in my SQL database. When I run the query without the `INTO minServer` and without using `NEW`, I get a valid (non-NULL) result. However, when I insert a new row into the table 'Visual' (using parameters identical to those in the query without `INTO minServer` and `NEW`), the result I get for minServer is NULL.

How can I resolve this issue?
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to fix this. Thank you!

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS inserimentoErogazione2;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER inserimentoErogazione2
AFTER INSERT ON Visual FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE minServer INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT ST.ID_Server INTO minServer
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT(S.ID_Server), S.BandaUtilizzata, S.Banda, S.ID_Paese,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY S.ID_Server, S.BandaUtilizzata, S.Banda, S.ID_Paese) AS num
    FROM (
                SELECT TV.ID_TipoVisual, V.ID_Visual, V.ID_Edizione, V.ID_IP, TV.ConsumoDati
                FROM Visual V NATURAL JOIN tipo_visual TV
            ) AS D
        INNER JOIN Connessione C ON D.ID_IP = C.IP
        NATURAL JOIN Utente U
        INNER JOIN Server S ON S.ID_Paese = U.ID_Paese
        INNER JOIN POP POP ON (S.ID_Server = POP.ID_Server AND D.ID_Edizione = POP.ID_Edizione)
    WHERE C.IP =  NEW.ID_IP
        AND D.ID_Edizione = NEW.ID_Edizione
    ORDER BY (0.7 * S.BandaUtilizzata + 0.3 * COALESCE(num, 0)) ASC
    ) AS ST
    LIMIT 1;

    
    INSERT INTO Erogazione (ID_Server, ID_Visual, QuantitaDati, DataInizioErogazione, DataFineErogazione)
    VALUES (minServer, NEW.ID_Visual, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL);

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here's the scenario in more detail:

When running the query independently (without INTO minServer and NEW), it works as expected. The problem arises when the trigger is invoked after a new row is inserted into 'Visual'. Parameters used for the insert are identical in both cases.

Comment: distinct is not a function so in DISTINCT(S.ID_Server) the brackets are ignored and the distinct is over all the selected columns.

Comment: Publishing sample data and expected outcome would help BTW  How do you know null is returned you aren't selecting minserver anywhere AND declared variables are not visible outside the SP anyway?

Comment: Add `SET @minServer = minServer, @ID_Visual = NEW.ID_Visual;` before INSERT. Check these variables values immediately after the trigger fires, in the same connection.